# Adding UI for CarPlay audio app

Tags: ios, user-interface, audio, carplay

I am adding a list (tableview) in my CarPlay audio app. In AppDelegate.m, I have

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ..........

    [MPPlayableContentManager sharedContentManager].dataSource = self;
    [MPPlayableContentManager sharedContentManager].delegate = self;

    return YES;
}
```

I also implemented MPPlayableContentDataSource methods in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfChildItemsAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
            return 3;

        case 1: 
            return 2;

        default:
            return 4;
    }
}

- (MPContentItem *)contentItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MPContentItem *contentItem = [[MPContentItem alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"container"];
    .................

    return contentItem;
}
```

However, the app crashes at switch (indexPath.row) and says 'Invalid index path for use with UITableView.  Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row.  Please use the category on NSIndexPath in UITableView.h if possible.' Did I do anything wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you manually creating `indexPath`?

Comment: No. I am not manually creating indexPath. I use the indexPath from the data source method -numberOfChildItemsAtIndexPath:.

Comment: Do you have a tableView and are you using this indexPath with it?

Comment: No. I don't have a list (tableView) yet. Now I think I see the problem: because I don't have a list (tableView) yet in my CarPlay app, the indexPath  form the data source method is invalid (zero in length and empty path). So how should I create a list (tableView) in a CarPlay app? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MPPlayableContentDataSource uses NSIndexPath differently than UITableView.
For `indexPath.row` to work indexPath has to contain exactly 2 elements but numberOfChildItemsAtIndexPath: can be called with indexPath consisting of 0 to 5 elements - that's why your code crashes

numberOfChildItemsAtIndexPath: in general should describe your navigation tree - provided indexPath to a specific node in your navigation it should return number of nodes to which you can navigate from this node

Some way to fix your code would be:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfChildItemsAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.length == 0) {
        // In a root of our navigation we have 3 elements
        return 3;
    }
    if (indexPath.length == 1) {
        switch ([indexPath indexAtPosition:0]) {
            case 0:
                // After tapping first item on our root list we see list with 3 elements
                return 3;
            case 1:
                // for second one we get list with 2 elements
                return 2;
            default:
                return 4;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I recommend watching WWDC video "Enabling Your App for CarPlay", especially from [6:00](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/719/?time=360) where they show nice example.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Secansoida. Last month I did use the same way as yours and it worked fine. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Do you happen to see the Now playing tab?  How did you do it?

Comment: @Secansoida, I could not list items correctly using contentItemAtIndexPath. So how can I allocate the position of MPContentItem in data source and delegate to return MPContentItem?

Comment: @DineshKumar I am not sure if I follow your question.
I think what you need to do is create some tree-like structure which would start with an array of nodes corresponding to items displayed at IndexPath with length 0. Each of these nodes can keep a reference to its children which in turn will keep reference to their children and so on. So to find a `MPContentItem` for a specific node you'd just walk through your tree.

Comment: @Secansoida I solved the issue and listed the items using MPContentItemDataSource...

Comment: Any chance you can translate this into swift? Specifically, the switch statement. What is the swift alternative to [indexPath indexAtPosition:0]

Comment: Answering my own question: The swift equivalent to [indexPath indexAtPosition:0] is indexPath[0]